# Prove that this function is continuous under the Sorgenfrey topology and not continuous under the order topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $\tau_U $and $\tau_S$ the order topology and the Sorgenfrey topology over $\mathbb R$. Prove that the map $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ given by $f(x)=x $ if $ x<1 $ and $ f(x)=x+2 $ if $ x \ge 1$ is $(\tau_S,\tau_S)-$continuous but not $(\tau_U ,\tau_U)-$continuous.

My try:
Clearly the only point we have problems is 1.

I've tried studying intervals the form $(3-\delta,3+\epsilon)$ and $(a,b)$ with $a<1$ and $b>1$, but I'm unable not to find and $U$ s.t. $f(U)\subset V$. And the same studying $[3-\delta,3+\epsilon)$,$[a,b).$

Is there a better way to approach this problem? What should I do?

Comment: To show $f$ continuous at 1 with Sorgenfrey topology, consider the preimage of $[3,3+\epsilon)$. To show it is not continuous at 1 in the order topology, it suffices to show that $f^{-1}[(2,4)]$ is not open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all $x$ (when the domain uses $\tau_S$), just use $[x,x+\delta)$ for small enough $\delta$, including for $x=1$.

Non-continuity in $\tau_U$: $f^{-1}[(2,4)]=[1,2)$, which is not open in $\tau_U$, though $(2,4)$ is.